# event that fires when handsontable loads

Tags: jquery, events, handsontable, event-triggers

I'm trying to do some DOM manipulations after [handsontable](http://handsontable.com) finishes loading/initializing.

Does handsontable have some event that is triggered after it finishes building itself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't find any such callback over at their [github](https://github.com/warpech/jquery-handsontable/blob/master/README.md#options), and I don't think you really need one. Just do your DOM changes after you've invoked `$("#container").handsontable()`. If it's because you're loading it with ajax, just invoke it at completion. Just follow their example [here](http://handsontable.com/demo/ajax.html).
<sub>`if (source === 'loadData') {...}`</sub>

If you're up to the challenge though, and depending on what version you've downloaded, we can dive into the source code and make some adjustments ourselves, because it is fairly simple. I am assuming that you're asking for callback after the handsontable has finished initializing without any ajax loads.

Follow me, let's dive right in.

---

### Changes in `jquery.handsontable.full.js`

Right, here it is, right after the settings, on line `2165` it says:

```
$.fn.handsontable = function (action) {...};
```

In there, we know everything is initialized, and luckily, the developer was nice enough to comment and label his stuff properly, so lets look at the lines inside it.

On line `2182` it says:

```
instance = new Handsontable.Core($this, currentSettings);
```

There's where they initialize the core things, at least that is what I can discern from the name, so adding a callback after this line should suffice as an `afterInit` callback.

So, all we need to do, is add a check for the callback in the settings provided by the user and then call it. I decided to add this callback after line `2184` because it's after the instantiation.
<sub>You can argue over where I put the callback and whether or not it should be inside the `Core` function and how I check if the setting is a function etc, but this gets the job done and it's easier this way.</sub>

So, on line `2182`

```
[...] 
instance = new Handsontable.Core($this, currentSettings); //<---- line 2182
$this.data("handsontable", instance);
instance.init(); //<---- line 2184

if(typeof(currentSettings.afterInit) == "function"){
    currentSettings.afterInit();
}
[...]
```

There, that's all we need to do! Now we can create a handsontable with an `afterInit` callback function.

```
$("#container").handsontable({
    startRows: 8,
    startCols: 6,
    rowHeaders: true,
    colHeaders: true,
    minSpareRows: 1,
    contextMenu: true,
    afterInit: function(){
        console.log("Handsontable initialized!");
    }
});
```

Don't be afraid to mess around with the source code, you'll learn a lot!

---

### Complete altered code

Here's the complete altered code starting from line `2165` to `2203` containing the `$.fn.handsontable` function:

```
$.fn.handsontable = function (action) {
  var i, ilen, args, output = [], userSettings;
  if (typeof action !== 'string') { //init
    userSettings = action || {};
    return this.each(function () {
      var $this = $(this);
      if ($this.data("handsontable")) {
        instance = $this.data("handsontable");
        instance.updateSettings(userSettings);
      }
      else {
        var currentSettings = $.extend(true, {}, settings), instance;
        for (i in userSettings) {
          if (userSettings.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
            currentSettings[i] = userSettings[i];
          }
        }
        instance = new Handsontable.Core($this, currentSettings);
        $this.data("handsontable", instance);
        instance.init();
        if(typeof(currentSettings.afterInit) == "function"){
            currentSettings.afterInit();
        }
      }
    });
  }
  else {
    args = [];
    if (arguments.length > 1) {
      for (i = 1, ilen = arguments.length; i < ilen; i++) {
        args.push(arguments[i]);
      }
    }
    this.each(function () {
      output = $(this).data("handsontable")[action].apply(this, args);
    });
    return output;
  }
};
```

Comment: Thanks! Indeed I need to start jumping into the source code more often with these plugins.  Thanks for the code samples.  I ended up just adding my code after my $("#container").handsontable(...) invocation.

Answer (score 10):

There is no need to alter code anymore as there are built in events for this:

`afterInit ()` - Callback fired after Handsontable instance is initiated.

`afterLoadData ()` - Callback fired after new data is loaded (by loadData method) into the data source array.

`afterRender ()` - Callback fired after Handsontable table is rendered.

For a full list of events [see here](https://github.com/warpech/jquery-handsontable/wiki/Events)

Comment: Im using ngHandsontable and this seems to fire 40 times rather than once?